# How do I use Perl to create multiple movie files out of a single movie file?

Tags: perl, video

Is there a way to use perl to create seven 1-minute long movies out of a 7-minute long quicktime movie (encoding H.264)? The movie would include video and sound as well.

**EDIT**: Based on DVK's comment, it seems that ffmpeg does this easily. There is a great wiki on how to install ffmpeg on your system: http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/MacOSXCompilationGuide

and then one can use the following command to divide let's say a 3-minute video into three one-minute sequence:

```
ffmpeg -i skinner.mov -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:01:00 -c copy smallfile1.mov -ss 00:01:00 -t 00:01:00 -c copy smallfile2.mov -ss 00:02:00 -t 00:01:00 -c copy smallfile3.mov
```

Any way of doing this with perl on a server?

Comment: Purely theoretically, it should be doable and possible, since Quicktime software can join multiple identical-format clips without re-encoding. See http://superuser.com/questions/133413/joining-h264-without-re-encoding.